# If button has class do something, if has different class do something else not working jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a button which opens a menu. On click if has class notOpen I have requested the menu to display. If it has class open then I have set it to change background colour as a test. However, this is not working. The button works when it has the class notOpen, but now when open. Why is this?

```js
var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');
var menu = $('.menu');

if ($(hamburger).hasClass('notOpen')) {
  $(hamburger).click(function() {
    menu.css('display', 'block');
    hamburger.toggleClass('open');
    hamburger.toggleClass('notOpen');
  });
};

if ($(hamburger).hasClass('open')) {
  $(hamburger).click(function() {
    menu.css('background-color', 'green');
  });
};
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="hamburger-icon" class="notOpen">Click me</button>

<div class="menu">SOME CONTENT</div>
```

E D I T

I am actually trying to show and hide the menu on click of the button, the code bellow is more similar to what I am trying to achieve.

```
var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');
var menu = $('.menu');

$(hamburger).on('click',function()  {

  if ($(hamburger).hasClass('notOpen')) {
    menu.css('display','block');
    hamburger.toggleClass('open');
    hamburger.toggleClass('notOpen');
  }

  if ($(hamburger).hasClass('open')) {
      menu.css('display','none');
      hamburger.toggleClass('open');
      hamburger.toggleClass('notOpen');
  };
```

Comment: Are you putting the above code inside any event,  If not, only one if condition will work. I hope you understood what I mean

Comment: I have not put this inside an event, can you show me what you mean please?

Comment: @Ajith if you mean a $( document ).ready(function() {, it is inside one yes.

Comment: I hope you know about ready functions, For understanding your issue, we need more explanations and code what you have done so far

Comment: Can you add more detail, specifically code that *demonstrates* the issue (possibly in two separate code snippets).  [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Do something like given below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');
    var menu = $('.menu');

    $(hamburger).click(function() {

        if($(this).hasClass('notOpen')) {
            menu.css('display','block');
            hamburger.toggleClass('open');
            hamburger.toggleClass('notOpen');
        };
        if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            menu.css('background-color','green');
        };

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

just add button click event properly then it will work's. You added `$(hamburger).click(function()` two times separate if conditions, so try to put it in `else if` condition

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hamburger-icon").click(function() {
        var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');
        var menu = $('.menu');

        if ($(hamburger).hasClass('notOpen')) {
            menu.css('display', 'block');
            hamburger.removeClass('notOpen');
            hamburger.addClass('open');
        } else if ($(hamburger).hasClass('open')) {
            menu.css('display', 'none');
            menu.css('background-color', 'green');
            hamburger.removeClass('open');
            hamburger.addClass('notOpen');
        };
    });
});
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#" class="active">Logo</a>
  <div id="myLinks" class="menu">
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <a id="hamburger-icon" class="icon notOpen">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

based on your edited question

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hamburger-icon").click(function() {
        var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');
        var menu = $('.menu');

        if ($(hamburger).hasClass('notOpen')) {
            menu.css('display', 'block');
            hamburger.removeClass('notOpen');
            hamburger.addClass('open');
        } else if ($(hamburger).hasClass('open')) {
            menu.css('display', 'none');
            menu.css('background-color', 'green');
            hamburger.removeClass('open');
            hamburger.addClass('notOpen');
        };
    });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="hamburger-icon" class="notOpen">Click me</button>

<div class="menu">SOME CONTENT</div>
```